# Is it legal to create a corporation for no reason?

Tags: united-states, corporate-law

Suppose a group of friends randomly decide to start a corporation and do nothing but have meetings and file paperwork, because they enjoy meetings and paperwork. While this isn't something most people would want to do "just for fun", is it legal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A business must be incorporated for a legal purpose (reason), and that reason must be stated when the business is registered; but that purpose can be to be incorporated and exist as a business.

It's common for businesses to be registered "for the purpose of conducting lawful business."

Comment: Would something like "for the purpose of providing experience with the legal requirements for creating, owning, and operating a corporation" be a valid reason?

Comment: @Someone Yes. That usually is called a training center or school.

Comment: It's extremely common for corporate bylaws in the US to be expressed in terms of "to engage in any lawful business" or similar. If you create a corporation "to develop the cheapest blood pressure meter this side of the Ozarks", once you either accomplish your goal or decide on a better one, your corporation no longer has a legal reason to exist and needs to be wound down. Save the goals for your vision statement.

Comment: Be advised that if you business is not profitable, you are not trying to make it profitable, and is not viewed as some form of legitimate not-for-profit business, it could be categorized as a hobby rather than a business which changes how losses can be treated for tax purposes. This seems to apply to an S-Corp every bit as much as an unincorporated individual, but C-Corps look like they may de different.

Comment: @KevinCathcart Now you're talking about a situation where someone is trying to obfuscate personal expenses and business losses for tax purposes; that's an explicitly illegal reason for a business function.

Comment: @KevinCathcart if the only purpose for having the corporation is to have a corporation, and one of the shareholders is willing to let the corporation have board meetings in their home and serve as registered agent, aren't the filing fees the only expenses (not enough for tax write-offs to matter for most people)?

Comment: @Someone Yes, you are correct and that situation would be fine. What Kevin is referring to would be more akin to a situation where that friend then claimed their lawn care or housekeeping as a corporate expense because the business met at their house. The situation is more likely to apply LLCs and S-corps that to C-corps.

Comment: @Someone Yeah Micheal's explanation is reasonable, but there could be other expenses. People who like meeting and paperwork may decide to have some nice company letterhead made which they may use to record the minutes of the board meetings. Or whatever else. Running a company for fun could be super cheap, but there are ways to make it expensive enough to want to actually expense things, and trying to do so with such a company is potentially problematic.